# I changed .live() to .on() but change is not reflected on the server

Tags: plugins, functions, jquery, deprecation

I downloaded a quantity increment plugin (themeszone Woocommerce ajax quantity) for my Wordpress site. Some of the Jquery was outdated this line specifically;

```
$('.tz-qty-cont').live('click', function(){
```

I found out .live was deprecated and needed to be changed to .on so i changed the line to

```
$(document.body).on('click', '.tz-qty-cont', function(){
```

However, I pushed the change to the server and inspected it with google console, I noticed my Wordpress site is not detecting the change? I'm on WP 5.7 and I'm pretty sure Jquery migrate is enabled even though i did not enable it which is odd as I thought it was removed in version 5.5 I thought about using Jquery migrater but then I found out that if my WP
version is higher than 5.6 then Jquery migrator wont actually help (not that its a solution in the first place)

[image: change on server not reflected on site]

Answer (score 1):

I never cleared the cache on my machine so the changes were not reflected on my site as it was loading a cached version of the webpage, but once I cleared my cache I then saw the changes.

Comment: Please use the edit link on your question to add additional information. The Post Answer button should be used only for complete answers to the question. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/236106)

Comment: it is a complete answer...have you not got the ability to comprehend the structure of a sentence? Let me elaborate, the "..." at the end of my answer is to signify to others that I am an idiot and forgot to clear my cache indicating that that was the issue, regardless I will edit it now, thank you so much though for taking time out of your day to be so critical, you have been most helpful